# Filter Realm Results array returns elements that should be filtered

Tags: swift, realm

Any ideas why this filter is not working correctly ?

```
for item in activeItems {
        print("item.product: \(item.product), \(item.spaceRequired)")
    }
```

returns

```
item.product: nil, 40.0
```

Filtering where product is nil

```
let f1 = activeItems.filter{$0.product != nil}
print("f1: \(f1)")
print("f1.count: \(f1.count)")
```

returns a count of ZERO but the array still appears to contain an item

```
f1: LazyFilterSequence<Results<AssortmentItem>>(_base: Results<AssortmentItem> <0x109ce2c90> (
    [0] AssortmentItem {
...

f1.count: 0
```

And then filtering and mapping just spaceRequired

```
let f11 = f1.filter{$0.product!.isProduct == true}.map({$0.spaceRequired})
    print("f11: \(f11)")
```

returns the same array with a single item

```
f11: LazyMapSequence<LazyFilterSequence<Results<AssortmentItem>>, Double>(_base: Swift.LazyFilterSequence<RealmSwift.Results<Merchandise_Manager.AssortmentItem>>(_base: Results<AssortmentItem> <0x109ce2c90> (
    [0] AssortmentItem {
```

And then trying to reduce crashes

```
let w = f11.reduce(0,+)
```

This seems to fix the problem

```
let width = Array(activeItems.filter{$0.product != nil}).filter{$0.product!.isProduct == true}.map({$0.spaceRequired}).reduce(0,+)
```

Is this a bug in Swift 5 or in Realm ?

EDIT: It looks like this is a bug in Realm's handling of things.

To be a bit cleared below is a more complete set of the Realm objects.

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

let activeDate: NSDate      = Date() as NSDate
let defaultWidth: Double    = 40.0

class MyObject: Object {
    @objc dynamic var number: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var name: String?       

    let items = List<ChildObject>()
}

extension MyObject {

    var activeItems: Results<ChildObject> {
        let activeDate = activeDate                  // Some globally defined value
        let active = items.filter("startDate <= %@ && (endDate >= %@ || endDate == nil)", activeDate, activeDate).sorted(byKeyPath: "number")
        return active
    }

    /// Works Correctly
    var totalWidth: Double {

        let width = Array(activeItems.filter{$0.product != nil}).filter{$0.product!.isProduct == true}.map({$0.spaceRequired}).reduce(0,+)
        let width2 = Array(activeItems.filter{$0.product == nil}.map({$0.spaceRequired})).reduce(0,+)

        return width+width2
    }

    /// Crashes
    var totalWidth: Double {

        let width = activeItems.filter{$0.product != nil}.filter{$0.product!.isProduct == true}.map({$0.spaceRequired}).reduce(0,+)
        let width2 = activeItems.filter{$0.product == nil}.map({$0.spaceRequired}).reduce(0,+)

        return width+width2
    }
}

class ChildObject: Object {
    @objc dynamic var parent: MyObject?
    @objc dynamic var number: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var product: Product?   
    @objc dynamic var name: String?    
    @objc dynamic var spaceRequired: Double = 40.0
    @objc dynamic var startDate: NSDate?
    @objc dynamic var endDate: NSDate?
}

extension ChildObject {
    var spaceRequired: Double {
        if let p = product {
            return p.width
        } else {
            return defaultWidth
        }
    }
}

class Product: Object {
    @objc dynamic var isProduct: Bool = false
    @objc dynamic var width: Double = 30.0
}
```

Comment: This question is hard to answer without knowing what an item looks like and more importantly their implementation as obviously .product property is nil at some point. Each piece of code demonstrates that .product is nil; f1 count is 0 because there are no objects that are not nil, f11 has a 0 count etc. You can probably troubleshoot this by going back farther to see where .product is set to nil, or perhaps make it a non-optional temporarily so the code crashes as soon as that happens. Just a thought.

Comment: @Jay - yes this issue seems to be that the filter is not actually filtering out the items with product property = nil and as a result the subsequent reduce() crashes because the spaceRequired property is a calculated property.  Converting to a Swift Array works correctly because the Array is empty.

Comment: Looking again at the code, you say *still appears to contain an item* however, the output presented in the question `f1.count: 0` clearly shows the array contains no items. I think you may be misinterpreting the console output - it's not telling you it contains an object. It's telling you of what kind of objects it would have *if* it had any.

Comment: @Jay The output listed the actual object and its properties - I just truncated the output with ...  I am assuming it has something to do with the "Lazy"

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of issues at work here but the main problem is that Realm Results are live updating; while you *can* filter data using the Swifty

```
let f1 = activeItems.filter{$0.product != nil}
```

it's going to give intermittent results since Realm doesn't know which items are filtered or not as .filter { is not a Realm function and Realm won't know what to update within the results.

You should generally use the built in Realm filtering mechanism

```
let results = realm.objects(ItemClass.self).filter("product != nil")
```

Those results will be live updating - if an object leaves the filter parameter, the results follow that. If an object matches the filter the results are updated as well.

I believe this [Github issue #2138](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/2138) provides some more light on the issue.

If you absolutely need static data, then I would suggest extending the Results class to return an array; like this

```
extension Results {
    func toArray() -> [Element] {
        return compactMap { $0 }
    }
}
```

Keeping in mind this will use more memory as Realm objects are lazy loaded and and array isn't.

**EDIT:**

There's some additonal information in the question so I crafted up a simple example trying to replicate the issue. There's a HouseClass object which contains a List of RoomClass objects and then the HouseClass is extended to return the total width of all of the rooms in its list.

```
class RoomClass: Object {
    @objc dynamic var room_name = ""
    @objc dynamic var width = 0
    @objc dynamic var length = 0
    @objc dynamic var belongs_to_house: HouseClass!
}

class HouseClass: Object {
    @objc dynamic var house_id = NSUUID().uuidString
    @objc dynamic var house_name = ""
    let rooms = List<RoomClass>()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "house_id"
    }
}

extension HouseClass {
    var totalWidth: Int {
        let width = Array(rooms).map {$0.width}.reduce(0,+)
        return width
    }

    var anotherTotalWidth: Int {
        let width = rooms.map {$0.width}.reduce(0,+)
        return width
    }
}
```

and then the code to get all of the houses and output their room widths based on two different functions (see the HouseClass extension)

```
let houseResults = realm.objects(HouseClass.self)

for house in houseResults {
    let w0 = house.totalWidth
    print(w0)

    let w1 = house.anotherTotalWidth
    print(w1)
}
```

I added 100 houses each with three rooms and ran the above code several times without crash.

Comment: Hmm... I am trying to filter a List for objects associated with another Realm object.  I have just updated the question with more complete class definitions.

Comment: @DuncanGroenewald Take a look at the Edit section of my answer. It' simpler than your example but conceptually it's summing up (in my case) the total width of the rooms in each house but it appears to be working correctly.

Comment: thanks for taking the time.  You need to add one more layer of objects to your model. For example 'RoomTypeClass { name: String, width: Double}' and have a property on 'RoomClass.type: RoomTypeClass?'.  Now on one of the rooms in your data set 'type = nil'.  Now filter your query to find only rooms where the 'type != nil' and then do the map/reduce.

Answer (score 0):

Count of `f1` is `0` so map is not worked.


 You can optimize your width calculation as following

```
let width = activeItems
      .filter { $0.product?.isProduct ?? false }
      .map { $0.spaceRequired }
      .reduce(0,+)
```